# Update all object value using global variable

Tags: javascript, object

After Update and show
In console cartype **Safari** but inside car object *Fiat*
Expected Output inside car object **Safari**

I dont want to use **car.type = Safari** in update function because i used //cartype inside multiple objects.

```js
var cartype = 'Fiat';

var car = {type:cartype, model:"500", color:"white"};

function update(){
  cartype = 'Safari';
}

function show(){
  console.log(cartype);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = car.type;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<button id="upd" onclick="update();">Update</button>
<button id="shw" onclick="show();">show</button>
```

Comment: The variables aren't synced

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your only hope is to set `car.type` to Safari.

```js
var cartype = 'Fiat';

var car = {type:cartype, model:"500", color:"white"};

function update(){
   cartype = 'Safari';
   car.type = cartype;
}

function show(){
  console.log(cartype);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = car.type;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<button id="upd" onclick="update();">Update</button>
<button id="shw" onclick="show();">show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a getter function to get the global cartype from `car.type`.

```js
var cartype = 'Fiat';

var car = {get type(){return cartype;}, model:"500", color:"white"};

function update(){
  cartype = 'Safari';
}

function show(){
  console.log(cartype);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = car.type;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<button id="upd" onclick="update();">Update</button>
<button id="shw" onclick="show();">show</button>
```

Learn more about getter function: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)